# Page not found after update to Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to get rid of the 404 Page not found error while updating to Codeigniter 3.0

I am using Ion Auth and HMVC libraries. I have fixed Ion Auth issue and I believe (not so sure) that I have fixed HMVC issues as well. If not than don't know how to debug ^_^ it. But I have updated both libraries with the latest one from their respective repos.

I have logged in successfully but when system try to loads the first page after login it is giving 404 error and here are the logs

```
DEBUG - 2015-03-17 10:51:51 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
DEBUG - 2015-03-17 10:51:51 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
ERROR - 2015-03-17 10:51:51 --> 404 Page Not Found: ../modules/admin/controllers/dashboard//index
```

***Notice: double slash in URI before last segment (index). Isn't it strange?***

I wonder what is wrong here. I have tried `uri_protocol` by setting `AUTO` and `REQUEST_URI` too but none of them worked.

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

and

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Now, I my development completely stuck. Can anyone help me to rid of this issue? Thanks a lot...!

**Routes info**

*application/config/routes.php*

```
$route['default_controller'] = "users/login";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

*application/modules/users/config/routes.php* This is for `Ion Auth`

```
$route['users/(:any)'] = "auth/$1";
```

Comment: in your redirect did you set your route in routes.php

Comment: I have added routes info in my question. Please go through it. BTW, The system was working fine in CI 2.2.1. It's just CI 3.0 give lot of troubles.

Comment: Are all your controllers & libraries capitalized need to be in CI3 & HMVC 3 also "auth/function/$1"; "auth/edit/$1"; auth I am thinking auth is module folder name? then you need to include "auth/controller/function/$1";

Comment: Classes name are capitalized but not the files name. Is filename is case sensitive too?

Comment: @mustang83 auth is the Ion Auth library name. I have just renamed it to `users` and moved to `modules` folder. I believe the placement should not be an issue, since I am using since CI 2.1.4

Comment: routes are only for controllers.

Comment: I have tried replacing the name with ucfirst style (as mentioned in docs) but no effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73135/discussion-between-mustang83-and-code-lover).

Comment: Anyone please help me to fix it...!

Comment: I'm having the issue. Works great on my localhost but when deployed online, the first page is a 404 page. Is anyone having the same problem when using the Codeigniter 3?

Answer (score 6):

I have fixed my 404 redirect issue by capitalizing all my class file names in the controller folder and model folder. 
So instead of main.php I did Main.php.

Hope this helps someone moving from CI 2 to CI 3.0

Comment: Hallelujah, this sorted my 404 issues when I moved from CI2 to 3!

Answer (score 0):

Capitalize all your controllers and models files.

Ex:
- controllers/Ajax.php

class Ajax extends MX_Controller {
   ... some magic stuff
}